# How to get email template content using template id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, programmatically

I need to get **email template content** like text/html using template id/code programmatically any help/suggestion much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the below helper method you can get the template data

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Helper;


use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Email\Model\Template as coreTemplate;


class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $template;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        coreTemplate $template
    )
    {
        $this->template = $template;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function templateText($templateId)
    {
            if (is_numeric($templateId)){
                $template = $this->template->load($templateId, 'template_id');
            }else {
                $template = $this->template->load($templateId, 'template_code');
            }


        $templateText = $this->template->getTemplateText();
        return $templateText;
    }
}
?>
```

You can add the following code to get the custom template content. Just replace the **$templateId** with you **email identifier name**.

```
<?php
namespace Your\Module\Model;

use Magento\Email\Model\TemplateFactory;

class YourClass
{
    protected $templateFactory;

    public function __construct(
        TemplateFactory $templateFactory
    ) {
        $this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
    }

    public function getCustomEmailTemplateContent($templateId)
    {
        $template = $this->templateFactory->create()->loadDefault($templateId);//Replace with your custom template name
        $templateText = $template->getTemplateText();

        return $templateText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Grazitti Dev  I'll try above code this works only if email templates stored in 'email_template' table so i need template text also if template created directly in modules by code not created/exist in admin template grid.

Comment: @ChandreshChauhan Updated the answer. Please try it out.

Comment: Thank you @Grazitti Dev its working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Email\Model\Template" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Model\EmailTemplateContent" />
</config>
```

**EmailTemplateContent.php**

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Model;

use Magento\Email\Model\Template;

class EmailTemplateContent extends Template
{
    /**
     * Get email template text by template ID
     *
     * @param int $templateId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTemplateText($templateId)
    {
        $template = $this->load($templateId);
        return $template->getTemplateText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing @nikhil but this method works only if email templates stored in table 'email_template' i need template text also if template created directly by code not created in admin template.